# Why does the Visual Studio conversion wizard 2010 create a massive SDF database file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I've opened a 2009 C++ sln in 2010 and run the Visual Studio 2010 conversion wizard. It seems to have done the conversion fine, but there's a 60 MB .sdf file created with the same name as my .sln file (apart from extension)! There was no sdf file before. I'm pretty sure when I've used the wizard on C# projects this file hasn't been created.

It looks like it's created to help the conversion wizard, but I don't see why it's left when the wizard has finished. The tables in the database are:

```
assoc_spans
assoc_text
base_class_parents
code_item_kinds
code_items
config_files
configs
file_map
file_signatures
files
parsers
projects
properties
refs
symbols
```

I assume I can just delete this file?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is the code browser database, it replaces the NCB file in earlier releases.  In VC++ 2010 the intellisense and browsing features have been [completely redesigned](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/05/27/rebuilding-intellisense.aspx) to provide greater functionality and accuracy.

Answer (score 12):

It's the browsing database. You may delete it; it will be recreated.