# Where are settings saved for solution in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, gitignore

I've been using Visual Studio 2012 for all of my .NET projects. For source control I've been using git.

Now my project consists of several helper libraries, but the important projects are the WEB and SERVICE projects. These should start together when debugging. Now I know how to set the settings I need to accomplish this, and they stick. However, if I pull the repo down to a new machine, those settings are gone. Below is my `.gitignore`. Am I missing something?

```
[Oo]bj/
[Bb]in/
$tf/
*.user
*.suo
*.[Cc]ache
*.bak
*.ncb
*.log 
*.DS_Store
*.xap
*.dbmdl
[Tt]humbs.db 
_ReSharper.*
*.resharper
Ankh.NoLoad]
*.cache
*.v11.suo
*.suo
*.pdb
*.csprojResolveAssemblyReference.cache
*.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt
*.mdf
*.ldf
```

I havn't edited or created this file, it is the one I used from my last place of employment.

Comment: This looks like it might be an older version of the community VS `.gitignore`.  You can find a more recent one at https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio's settings are stored in the `.suo` file.

This is in your `.gitignore` so they will not be pulled from any other repo.

[I would not suggest removing it from your `.gitignore` file though.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72298/should-i-add-the-visual-studio-suo-and-user-files-to-source-control)

Comment: What if I added it to the repo once, and then put the exception in .gitignore so it doesn't commit it again. Is this possible?