# What are the files you should not check into source control for a new ASP.net project?

Tags: asp.net, version-control

There is a new ASP.Net project in your company/team, be it web form or MVC. Someone have to create it first. So John Doe created it.

1. What are the files that John should not check into version control? sln? proj? Anything else?
2. If John do not check in sln or proj, how should the rest of the team open the project after they check out from version control for the first time?

Answer (score 2):

You should check in `.sln` and `.proj` files.

Some of the files/folders which you typically do not check in are:

- `*.suo`
- `*.user`
- `packages` folder
- `bin` and `obj` folders
- typically, any folder starting with a dot, e.g. `.vs`
- `node_modules`

Depending on the project type, there will certainly be more files/folders which are typically not kept under version control.

BTW: see also this question: [Should I add the Visual Studio .suo and .user files to source control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72298/should-i-add-the-visual-studio-suo-and-user-files-to-source-control)