# Visual Studio Build platform varies for different users on the same project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, build

So this is just a general question regarding behavior in the Visual Studio IDE.  We have solution files with project from our code repositories.  I can sync to get the latest changes, and view the project on my machine and the platform target of the project may be x86.  My coworker, can perform the same sync, open the same project in the same version of visual studio on their machine and it will open as x64 .  Also mine may open in Debug while his may open in say Release.  I would have thought these configs would be specific to the project and therefore saved with it but it appears to be a local setting that is driving these settings?? Should I be worried, is there something wrong here??  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: pretty sure intended build platform, and release mode are "user" settings on a project, not "project" settings.  They are by default (at least with most source control?) not checked in

Comment: Im getting that I guess I just find it strange that wouldn't be a project setting.

Comment: The build settings are indeed per user, which in my view is broken. This is also true of the paths to libraries in the file system, which is also very confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to let you reload your solution in the latest state you leaved it, Visual Studio uses two types of files ".user" and ".suo" file, these files will be created at some point when you make changes to your projects/solution, if the file exists in your folder, Visual Studio will load it as part of the solution to change some settings, if the file doesn't exists, Visual Studio will load the solution with the default values. These files should not be committed to the source control since they are intended to respect "per user" settings.

If you want to test this, be sure to get the source code to a completely clean folder (you and your colleague).

There's nothing to worry about, you can safely remove them or have them in your working directory.

For additional information about these files you can review this post: [Should I add the Visual Studio .suo and .user files to source control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72298/should-i-add-the-visual-studio-suo-and-user-files-to-source-control)

Comment: Thanks very much!  That really clarifies it for me at this point.