# where does visual studio put user app.config files/settings

Tags: c#, visual-studio, app-config

I've looked in C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming and C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local for my application that I'm debugging in Visual Studio 2015, but can't find it there.

I'm trying to blow away the setting value, but can't find it.

Where do user settings go for visual studio projects i'm debugging?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the specific project's settings you are currently debugging, they are stored in

> yourproject.exe.config

file located side by side with your exe in bin\debug (or bin\release) folder

Answer (score 1):

The file is stored inside this path "bin/debug/app.config", if you make changes while debugging, those changes should appear there. Just remember that this file is overwritten with the "app.config" from the project root each time you run the application on Visual Studio IDE.

Comment: It isn't being overwritten each time I run. Maybe if I do a clean, but in between normal build + runs, the settings are sticking.

Answer (score 0):

They are in the .suo and .usr file which is in a hidden ".vs" folder in the root directory of the project.  An explanation of what these files hold can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72662/5481661)  You'll have to show hidden files in order to find it.

The whole folder is user specific.  I sometimes find the need to delete the whole folder when VS is running very slow or when I have a setting I played with and want it back to default.  VS will recreate the folder, but I would save a backup in case.

Comment: I only see a .suo file, and it's basically not plain text. Does that seem right? I guess I can't edit it by hand.

Comment: @StealthRabbi, oh I see, you're trying to manually edit it for a specific setting value?

Comment: Either edit it, or just blow it away to go back to a default state. I deleted the .suo file, but it still seems to have the old values.

Comment: @StealthRabbi, which setting are you trying to change?

Comment: application-specific settings that I defined in Settings.settings / app.config.